# Render error while ListView builder inside alert dialog content

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make ListView.builder as an alertdialog content...but it is showin RENDER errror...and when I do the same with scaffold body..it works ...

I have made a method named Mycontent...
If I apply this MyContent to scaffold body, it works but it does not work with alert content....this is what making me confuse...between alert content and scaffold body

here is my code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String result = '';
  List <String> names=['A','B','C','D'];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(result),
      ),
      body: Center(
    child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final result = await openDialog();
            if (result == null || result.isEmpty) return;
            setState(() {
              this.result = result;
            });
          },
          child: Text('Select Color'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ),
    );
  }

 

  Future<String?> openDialog() {
    return showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Select Your Name'),
              content: MyContent(),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                    child: Text('Submit'))
              ],
            ));
  }

  MyContent() {

      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: names.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return Text(names[index]);
                }),
          )
    ],
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your ListView inside SizedBox or Container and give it to specific heifgt and width, add `shrinkWrap: true,` inside `ListView.builder()`, dont use `RaisedButton` use [**`ElevatedButton`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) because `RaisedButton` is [deprecated](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

```
MyContent() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: names.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(names[index]);
          }),
    );
  }
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks...but actually my query Is regarding scaffold body vs alert content...why it works with scaffold body and not working with alert content

Comment: What was your exact problem?

Comment: If I placed My code of Mycontent() as scaffold body...it works....than why should I wrap it inside sized box for  alert content...thats my question

Comment: @IrfanGanatra when we `SizedBox` or `Container` it gives the height and width of that widget.